# Jenkins and local PyCharm running tests using different path

Tags: jenkins, pycharm, pytest, python-unittest

I am checking out a project from git repo. The project was run on Jenkins. One of the unit tests file is reading the file with filename:

```
filename = os.path.join(self.config_dir, name, 'my_parameters.json')
```

This works fine on Jenkins, but failed to work on my local machine using pyCharm. On the local machine, I have to change the filename to:

`filename = '../' + os.path.join(self.config_dir, name, 'my_parameters.json')` to make the test works.

It seems that Jenkins and local pyCharm is running test files in different path. How do I resolve this issue to make the code running in both machines? Thank you!

Comment: `if not os.path.isfile(filename): filename = '../' + filename`?

Comment: Utilize `__file__` and join a relative path to that should make it independent of the working directory